# Does new C11 standard support lambdas?

Tags: c, standards, lambda

We know C++11 does have lambdas but does C11?

Answer (score 5):

No it doesn't, you can check the [Changes from C99](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29#Changes_from_C99) in the wiki

Answer (score 4):

No. No, it doesn't. Not at all. Nope.

Answer (score 4):

No. It doesn't. This is a C++11 only feature.